# Can I addCommand a file and commit it?how?

Tags: eclipse, exception, jgit

When I use `org.eclipse.jgit, addCommand(file)`,it will not work, and will have an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Entry not found by path: C:\workspace\eclipse\JGit\git.java
```

what can cause it and how to solve it ?

Comment: Please add the code you are using to do this to the question.

Answer (score 0):

My [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook) has examples for this at

- https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/AddFile.java and
- https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/CommitFile.java,

does it work if you do it like these samples?

Comment: hi，when I copy your demo CloneRemoteRepository and have a try, there is an exception Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
,which is just the problem a few days ago I met， I can't solve it， and I can't have a deep understangding of JGit~~thanks so much

Comment: There are dependencies on a few additional jars, if you cloned jgit-cookbook you can get an Eclipse project with ```mvn eclipse:eclipse```, this will then include the following jars: org.eclipse.jgit-2.3.1.201302201838-r.jar, jsch-0.1.46.jar, commons-io-2.4.jar. In your own project you will need to add at least jsch for a Java based SSH implementation

Comment: FYI, I have just upgrade jgit-cookbook to JGit 3.0.0, the dependend jar-files are now as follows, with commons-io being used by jgit-cookbook, but not required for jgit itself.

com.googlecode.javaewah:JavaEWAH:java-source:sources:0.5.6
com.jcraft:jsch:java-source:sources:0.1.46
commons-io:commons-io:java-source:sources:2.4
org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:java-source:sources:3.0.0.201306101825-r